# NGXS iif Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1 error

Tags: ngxs

I'm getting an unexplainable error with NGXS' `iif` operator.

I've copy and pasted this update patch because its what I built for an exact duplicate table data setup in the same project. However, this instance has an error I cannot get around.

```
ctx.setState(
  patch({
    table: patch({

      rows: iif<any>( <-- Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.ts(2558)

        (tasks: any) => tasks?.some((task: any) => task.id === updatedTask?.id),
        updateItem<any>((task: any) => task.id === updatedTask?.id, patch(updatedTask))
      ),
    }),
  })
);
```

Comment: This iif statement looks like the iif vb function, it takes 3 arguments, the boolean condition, the action if the condition is true and the action if the condition is false

Comment: It was auto-imported from RxJS by accident!